# Knowing the name of the AWS Beanstalk environment, how do I get the environment's corresponding platform through commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The application name of AWS Beanstalk is Agile-Cloud.

There are three environments in application：

Agile-Cloud-dev , Agile-Cloud-prod ,  Agile-Cloud-stage

Now that I know the environment name, I want to know the name of the platform corresponding to the environment through the command.

I will try the command "eb init Agile-Cloud-dev" , but it create a new application name "Agile-Cloud-dev"

What kind of command do I need to use to achieve this purpose?

Now the environment name "Agile-Cloud-dev" corresponding platform is "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7"

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `eb init Agile-Cloud`, where "Agile-Cloud" is the name of your application. You will also be promoted to choose one among the three environments you have during `eb init`